# No data in 'rows' for Youtube Analytics API

Tags: youtube, youtube-analytics-api

I am running the following query with Youtube Analytics API

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
start_date = (now - datetime.timedelta(days=4)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

end_date = (now - datetime.timedelta(days=3)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

args = {
    'metrics': 'views,estimatedMinutesWatched',
    'dimensions': 'subscribedStatus',
    'ids': 'channel==<my_channel_id>',
    'startDate': start_date,
    'endDate': end_date
}

analytics_query_response = youtube.reports().query(**args).execute()
```

I am using youtube analytics api version 2 and changed the end_date parameter to endDate and start_date to startDate and I am getting the following response

```
{u'kind': u'youtubeAnalytics#resultTable', u'rows': [], u'columnHeaders': [{u'dataType': u'STRING', u'columnType': u'DIMENSION', u'name': u'subscribedStatus'}, {u'dataType': u'INTEGER', u'columnType': u'METRIC', u'name': u'views'}, {u'dataType': u'INTEGER', u'columnType': u'METRIC', u'name': u'estimatedMinutesWatched'}]}
```

I get the 'rows' in response but it's empty. When I try with the same parameters in Youtube API Explorer, it gives me the result for 'rows'.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add the scope: "Youtube".

Then, try to delete the file: "Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-..." located in my case at: ".\users\admin\appdata\roamming\YouTubeAnaltycis.Auth.Store"

It´s works for me.

Best regards.

Comment: My scope variable looks like this:

YOUTUBE_READONLY_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly'

can you please give me a code sample? Thanks

Comment: I think this is what you need: 'googleapis.com/auth/youtube'. C. Net example: OAuthcredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { YouTubeAnalyticsService.Scope.Youtube,YouTubeAnalyticsService.Scope.YtAnalyticsReadonly },
                   user, CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("YouTubeAnalytics.Auth.Store")).Result;

Comment: Where the file **YouTubeAnaltycis.Auth.Store** is located in Ubuntu?